# Posting JavaScript/jQuery variables to another PHP page and redirect to that page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I’m trying for a long time to:

1. Execute a .js file on the client side (succeeded).
2. Pass the returned object (the returned variables) to another php page as an array for further work with them (succeeded with problems).

The 1. Point I’m able to execute with no problem on the client side with

Some `PHP` code to prepare the variables for the jQuery part, for example like the `jobJSPath[0]`.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() {
        // $jobJSPath[0] holds the path to the job1.js file
        var scriptPath = "<?php echo $jobJSPath[0]; ?>"; 
        $.getScript(scriptPath, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            // Call the function
            var job = job1();
            console.log(job); // shows all the return parameters from job1() as an Object;

           // push the return parameters from the Object into the result array without the labels
            var result = [];
            $.each(job, function(index, value) {
                //window.alert(index + ": " + value);
                result.push(value);
            });
```

For the 2. Part I use an `Ajax` call

```
        $.ajax({        
            type: 'POST',
            data: {result : result},
            url: 'executedJobs.php',
            }).done(function(data) {
                var redirectUrl = "executedJobs.php";
                var form = $('<form action="' + redirectUrl + '" method="post">' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="result" value="'+ data +'" />' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="job_batch_id" value="<?php echo $jobsArray[0];?>" />' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="<?php echo $jobsArray[1];?>" />' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="job_name" value="<?php echo $jobsArray[2];?>" />' +
                '</form>');
                $('body').append(form);
                $(form).submit();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is:

When I’m being redirected to the executedJobs.php all my echo strings there are being posted 2 times, one time without the variables outputs any directly after that with the outputs like this:

> **Job Return-Arguments**
>
> **Job Return-Arguments** 
>   Array ( [0] => ixFm5QjDGZ4PWLC1phPcSZUF4 3Byi23bxr6sd6Hw9JSOpLBEcafkzgfDFcO0jO4DcVCk67aH4aDcqiQYTEdSsGrnufo7MfXronhl1IRL9Luz7Wq8dgZVvON1STUGJKrA26NdWqe1teHQ4hbOWojyzyEC6s8aHs991qZDWbp 54UCUF4w2UV5c2INB1F8usENsFAg4vT8LNAqMzpNiqr Bhp5MC6kSLhlbXLHozsGVdyej63rANnPMWQflpjXtEsmD6Hbu7Ut2efHwPr7u9A9gYjcGPlrtkC2ZDjThKYx6wylRb6YNUHMrb6nNkwhlaMla8iiTPrfEO6v5WSBB7ubuIZreadDd2Gr0p69xJtCdWZkvlisn4MbJsE e0xWf8xjjGNexNPABGbXH29JYgt2iejC9 tuvo6mEFreUapRjGuLnOqCssvKORENrClI34ioTXnpx9BmmMDXn5OLcXcmtPHb0kAVDEJ0ZfnrqX7MGd2z3XFXGYk [1] => ixFm5QjDGZ4PWLC1phPcSZUF4 3Byi23bxr6sd6Hw9JSOpLBEcafkzgf [2] => DFcO0jO4DcVCk67aH4aDcqiQYTEdSsGrnufo7MfXronhl1IRL9Luz7Wq8dgZVvON1STUGJKrA26NdWqe1teHQ4hbOWojyzyEC6s8aHs991qZDWbp 54UCUF4w2UV5c2INB1F8usENsFAg4vT8LNAqMzpNiqr Bhp5MC6kSLhlbXLHozsGVdyej63rANnPMWQflpjXtEsmD6Hbu7Ut2efHwPr7u9A9gYjcGPlrtkC2ZDjThKYx6wylRb6YNUHMrb6nNkwhlaMla8iiTPrfEO6v5WSBB7ubuIZreadDd2Gr0p69xJtCdWZkvlisn4MbJsE e0xWf8xjjGNexNPABGbXH29JYgt2iejC9 tuvo6mEFreUapRjGuLnOqCssvKORENrClI34ioTXnpx9BmmMDXn5OLcXcmtPHb0kAVDEJ0ZfnrqX7MGd2z3XFXGYk )
>
> **Job-Batch-ID:** ,**Job-ID:** and **Jobname:**
>
> **Job-Batch-ID:** 1, **Job-ID:** 1 and **Jobname:** job1

I’m suspecting that this happens because of the `Ajax POST` call followed by the `.done()` section with `var form =` and at the end `$(form).submit()`. The thing is when I’m using the `window.location.href = "executedJobs.php?result=" + data+ "";` in the `.done()` action instead 0f the `var form =` followed by the `$(form).submit()` action I get the same echo duplicates and all the passed data are shown in the URL because of the `?result=" + data+ "";` part which I’m trying to avoid also, therefore I use the form with the `type = “hidden”`.

I could instead of the whole `$.ajax({………..}).done({………..})` part do only this:

```
var redirectUrl = "executedJobs.php";
var form = $('<form action="' + redirectUrl + '" method="post">' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="result" value="'+ result +'" />' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="job_batch_id" value="<?php echo $jobsArray[0];?>" />' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="<?php echo $jobsArray[1];?>" />' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="job_name" value="<?php echo $jobsArray[2];?>" />' +
                '</form>');
$('body').append(form);
$(form).submit();
```

But then my `result array` is being passed as a `string` and not as an `array` to the `executedJobs.php`.

Can someone please help me with passing the result array from point 1 with all the other data defined in the `var form =` to the `executedJobs.php` without getting the echoed duplicates as shown above?

I hope I was clear enough with the post, I tried to explain as much as I could. Please do ask if something is still not clear enough.

Comment: Why don't you just include the inputs in the jQuery POST request as data? Then in the `executedJobs.php` you can retrieve them using `$_GET`.

Comment: @Diederik I'll try it, will I be automatically redirected to the `executedJobs.php` or during I still have to do it in the `.done()` section with `window.location.href = "executedJobs.php?`?

Comment: You won't be redirected at all. That's what an AJAX request does. If you want to be redirected, just remove the AJAX call bit and only do the form submit part. You already propose this yourself, but I don't see why this isn't working. What's your code for `executedJobs.php` if you do this?

Comment: @Diederik I tried that already and the problem with that is that the `result` array is being passed as a string and not as an array to the `executedJobs.php` and I need it to be an array on the `executedJobs.pho`

Comment: @Diederik I don't have an access turn my PC at the moment. But on the `executeJobes.php` I'm doing this for example for the `result` array from the `jQuery` page `$myArray = $_POST['result'];` then `print_r($myArray);`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Best thing to do is to convert your `results` into JSON format. JSON is a lightweight data-interchange format and it is language independent. Therefore, it is one of the best formats to exchange information between for example PHP and JS. Then in your php file you can just use `json_decode` and you have yourself a PHP array again. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: @Diederik I'll try it out and report back if I'll have any other questions. Just to be clear for this Json approach I have to use only the form submit part and remove my Ajax call, correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is because two times the "executedJobs.php" file is executed. 
Once when the ajax call is called, i.e., the url of ajax call is executedJobs.php
Another is when the form is submitted in the success function call of ajax call.

So, you are receiving the two sets of output.

You can try to save the result in cookies, if using HTML5 in localstorage.
And access that data to other page, on load of the page.
Else you want to go with same approach, then you can use two different Files for ajax call and form submission.

Comment: I would not advise to use local storage for something as tedious as this. It's just retrieving data from a form. I'd say that the proposed approach is wrong to begin with, and using local storage is not the solution.

Comment: @Premalatha I'll try this when I'll be in front of my PC again and report back